# The meaning of "be it practices"

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive-mood

Could you help me understand the meaning of "be it practices" in the context below?

> People will always find some aspect of another culture distasteful, be it practices, a way of treating friends or relatives, or simply a food that they can not manage to get down with a smile.

Comment: The form *be it X* (always followed by ***or** X [or Z...]* is equivalent to ***if/whether** it's X [or y or z]*. Someone else will have to provide the formal grammar/syntax background.

Answer (score 2):

*be it...or...* is a common (albeit formal) construction in English that basically means the same thing as *whether it is...or...*.

In your case, the sentence is saying "People will always find something they don't like about foreign cultures, whether it is their practices, how they treat friend/relatives, or bad food."

Answer (score 0):

It is the present subjunctive mood.

Comment: But this hardly answers the main thrust of the question (about what the string means).